# Cannot load JDBC driver class 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver'

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-server-2005, jtds

I have some problems with jtds.

I'm using Hibernate, Tomcat 5.5 on Linux Red Hat Server, SQL Server 2005 with WIndows Server

I save the library into Web-iNF/lib and i'm using the version jtds-1.2.2

I got the Error Message

> 16:56:17,561 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:78 - Cannot load JDBC driver
>   class 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver'

can some one explain what i'm doing wrong?

Here the connection definition.

```
<Resource name="pr/jdbc/dsConn" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="example" password="test1234" driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/example" />
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

best regards

Comment: Sounds like you're just missing the jar file from your classpath. Unfortunately you haven't told us anything about that side of things.

Comment: If your directory is really called Web-iNF/lib, that may cause problems. It should be WEB-INF/lib

Comment: Not related to your problem: But are you aware that Tomcat 5.5 is end-of-live September 2012. You should really think about upgrading. There is also a newer version of jTDS available (1.2.5)

Comment: Had you added this .jar file to your `Tomcat's classpath` before continuing ?

Comment: if you think you added the jar, you could check if this driver class (net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver) actually is inside the jar

Comment: Just to clarify, the file goes in your *Tomcat*'s WEB-INF/lib, not your webapp's WEB-INF/lib.